# way to store images in cockroachdb as blob

Tags: cockroachdb

Can we store files / images on cockroachdb and use it where S3 would otherwise by used ? So , both private and public images with different permissions can be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB is not currently well suited to be a blob store.
Our [max size recommendation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/bytes.html#size) is 1MB.

In addition, the maximum range size is 64MB by default, with the smallest range being a row, including all the previously written values of that row within the last 24h (default GC TTL).

That said, the 1MB is not enforced (just a recommendation), and the 64MB range size and 24h TTL are configurable through [zone configs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/configure-replication-zones.html) so you're very welcome to try it, you're likely to encounter some issues though.